# How do I play the backend role with react?

Tags: reactjs, backend, trading

I'm planning to make buying and selling knowledge trading system in university

so i have to make bulletin board and add communication and comment system, user infromation

and make able to trade the points each other..

So the question is can i do this back end work by react and sql??

If not,

Can you tell me how to implement this?

Comment: For a JavaScript solution consider Node.js + Express on the back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a front-end js framework that will help you to make the interface of the app.

I recommend you make the backend in Firebase that is a Google service that offers must of the basics backend functionalities for basics Apps.
If you're looking for something more robust try out with Django, Node, or the new Deno framework.

Good luck.